# Is there any API for developer for UWP apps?

Tags: uwp

I searched for developer API, but could find the submission API only. Is there any API for developer that retrieves my app's install count, status, rating etc of all my apps, I searched, but could not find. Is there any such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rating status you can use Store API, see details from [Get app ratings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-app-ratings). With this restful api you will be able to the data related to rating about your app.

To get app reviews you can see this doc: [Get app reviews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-app-reviews).

To get the install data, please see here [Get app installs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-app-installs)